# Using a custom firefox profile for selenium but not changing it

Tags: python, selenium

I'd like my selenium web driver to launch a firefox browser that only has the addon "adblock plus" enabled. I created a new profile with this addon, and it works fine, but everytime I make some changes to this firefox profile, like resize it or add a bookmark for example, my profile "saves" this change.

Is there any way to make it such that my profile doesn't save that change? Or, in other words, start a new profile each time with only one single addon enabled? I'm using python, and I'd appreciate any help or pointers in the right direction.

Thanks! If my question is not clear, I'm happy to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove your **annotations, bookmarks, favorite icons, input history, keywords, and browsing history** by deleting your *places.sqlite* file from your profile before starting each new session.

[More about *places.sqlite*.](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite)

[Find your *places.sqlite* file in your profile folder.](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data)